# Scrollbar for output chunk in Quarto

Tags: r, scroll, scrollbar, chunks, quarto

I would like to plot multiple plots from a chunk and add a `scrollbar` to the output of that chunk. I see [here](https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/html-code.html) that this could be done for Code Overflow, but I am not sure how to scroll the output instead of adding all the plots below each other like in the example below:

````
---
title: "Scrollbar in output chunk"
format:
  html:
    code-overflow: wrap
---

Here is some example code:

```{r}
#| code-overflow: wrap
library(ggplot2)
for(i in unique(iris$Species)) {
  print(
    ggplot(iris[iris$Species == i, ], aes(x = Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
      geom_point()
  )
}
```
````

Output:

[image]

As we can see from the output, all the plots are shown below each other, but I would like to have a scrollbar chunk so it doesn't show all plot at once. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to add a scroll option to the output of a chunk in `Quarto`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a div before the chunk, e.g.

````
---
title: "Scrollbar in output chunk"
format: html
    
css: styles.css
---

Here is some example code:

:::{.scrolling}

```{r}

library(ggplot2)
for(i in unique(iris$Species)) {
  print(
    ggplot(iris[iris$Species == i, ], aes(x = Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
      geom_point()
  )
}
```

:::
````

**styles.css**

```
.scrolling {
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

[image]

If you do not want the scrolling for the code, than you could do this:

````
---
title: "Scrollbar in output chunk"
format: html
    
css: styles.css
---

Here is some example code:

```{r}
#| eval: false

library(ggplot2)
for(i in unique(iris$Species)) {
  print(
    ggplot(iris[iris$Species == i, ], aes(x = Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
      geom_point()
  )
}
```

:::{.scrolling}

```{r}
#| echo: false

library(ggplot2)
for(i in unique(iris$Species)) {
  print(
    ggplot(iris[iris$Species == i, ], aes(x = Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
      geom_point()
  )
}
```

:::
````

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can create a css file with a defined `max-height` and `overflow-y` and add it to your chunk with `class`. Note that this will also include the code in the scrolling section. Also note that if you want a *text* output to be scrollable, you should use `class-output` instead of `class` in your chunk options.

````
---
title: "scrollable-output"
format: html
---

```{css, echo = FALSE}
.output {
max-height: 500px;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Here is some example code

```{r}
#| class: output
library(ggplot2)
for(i in unique(iris$Species)) {
  print(
    ggplot(iris[iris$Species == i, ], aes(x = Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
      geom_point()
  )
}
```
````

[image]